# Произвольное отключение жесткого диска

Tags: windows, hdd, железо

Во время простоя ПК (минут 10) экран тухнет, ПК продолжает гудеть. На действия клавы/мыши не реагирует. Нажимаю на системнике "перезагрузка", выдает "the boot device is not found...". Захожу в Биос, а там жесткого диска не видно. Выключаю комп кнопкой, включаю и все ок - Винда загружается, как при обычном включении, только тупит первое время сильно, что даже ярлыки подгружаются примерно минуту. И так по новой. Что может быть?

UPD: Windows 10 x64, мат. ASUS M4A87TD EVO, ЖД Seagate 1000. Victoria "говорит Good"

Comment: Думаю стоит подумать о замене диска.

Comment: Для начала, скачать софт для считывания и анализа S.M.A.R.T диска

Comment: Больше похоже на дебильный энергосберегающий режим самого диска. Не хватает: модели диска, версии винды, и хотя бы модель материнки.

Comment: Всё что угодно может быть - и проблемы с БП и тупо шлейф отваливается и какой-то режим энергосбережения неправильно отрабатывает.

Comment: Возьми на тест заведомо исправный блок питания и проверь.

Comment: Что `mhdd` говорит?